# Add a UIGestureRecognizer to custom drawRect or UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, uibezierpath

I created a custom view using `drawRect`. All of the drawing logic is done in that method and I didn't split up the view into separate sub views (drawing using `UIBezierPath`)

I need to add a gesture recognizer to the corner of this new custom view - but as the completed view is one "drawing" in the context - it isn't thought of as a seperate UIView - and the gesture recognizes all portions of the drawing .

Is it possible to recognize the gesture only when a corner is grabbed?

Can my view somehow cache the "right corner" and in the delegate of a gesture recognizer return "NO" in

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
```

Comment: Why cache? Is the target a bezier? Did you try hit testing it?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a piece of code that does just that

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    if (gestureRecognizer != self.tapGestureRecognizer) {
        return YES;
    }
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.targetView];
    return [self.bezierPath containsPoint:touchLocation];
}
```

Comment: Tried that - but for some reason it always returns  no - I'm afraid that the resolution of touches for the pan gesture and the containsPoint is to far apart... It always returns NO Printing description of self->_rightBottomHandle:
<UIBezierPath: 0x10931b690; <MoveTo {320, 568}>,
 <LineTo {320, 558}>,
 <MoveTo {320, 568}>,
 <LineTo {310, 568}>

Here is a print screen after touching the bezier path:

Printing description of point: 
(CGPoint) point = (x=311.5, y=556)

Comment: make sure the view you drew on is the same as the one you call `locationInView:` for

Answer (score 0):

You could validate the location of the touch point as followed:

```
CGPoint point = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self];
```

Now check, whether the point is located in a defined region:

```
if(!CGRectContainsPoint([myDefinedCGRect, point))
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Avner wanted to hit test UIBezierPath not the rect

Comment: "corner of this new custom view" - in more general, a kind of region/rect :)